# How to deserialize Xcom strings in Airflow?

Tags: json, jinja2, airflow, json-deserialization

Consider a DAG containing two tasks: `DAG: Task A >> Task B` (BashOperators or DockerOperators). They need to communicate through XComs.

- `Task A` outputs the informations through a one-line json in stdout, which can then be retrieve in the logs of `Task A`, and so in its *return_value* XCom key if `xcom_push=True`. For instance : `{"key1":1,"key2":3}`
- `Task B` only needs the `key2` information from `Task A`, so we need to deserialize the *return_value* XCom of `Task A` to extract only this value and pass it directly to `Task B`, using the jinja template `{{xcom_pull('task_a')['key2']}}`. Using it as this results in `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'str object' has no attribute 'key2'` because *return_value* is just a string.

For example we can deserialize Airflow Variables in jinja templates (ex: `{{ var.json.my_var.path }}`). Globally I would like to do the same thing with XComs.

**Edit:** a workaround is to convert the json string into a python dictionary before sending it to Xcom (see below).

Answer (score 2):

A workaround is to create a custom Operator (inherited from BashOperator or DockerOperator) and augment the `execute` method:

1. execute the original `execute` method
2. intercepts the last log line of the task
3. tries to `json.loads()` it in a Python dictionnary
4. finally return the output (which is now a dictionnary, not a string)

The previous jinja template `{{ xcom_pull('task_a')['key2'] }}` is now working in `task B`, since the XCom value is now a Python dictionnary.

```py
class BashOperatorExtended(BashOperator):
    def execute(self, context):
        output = BashOperator.execute(self, context)
        try: 
            output = json.loads(output)
        except:
            pass
        return output

class DockerOperatorExtended(DockerOperator):
    def execute(self, context):
        output = DockerOperator.execute(self, context)
        try: 
            output = json.loads(output)
        except:
            pass
        return output
```

But creating a new operator just for that purpose is not really satisfying..

Answer (score 1):

You can add a post function to the BashOperator that deserialize the result and push all keys separately

```
def _post(context, result):
    ti = context["ti"]
    output = json.loads(result)
    for key, value in output.items():
        ti.xcom_push(key, value)

BashOperator(
    task_id="task_id",
    bash_command='bash command',
    post_execute=_post
)
```

Comment: Yes indeed, to retrieve directly the first level keys.